# Trying to past a string in the dataframe$ colum to make a loop of plots

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot 20 lines in a graph, and then I want to use a loop to save me work. How can I do it? I tried to use paste0 in my dataframe, but of course will return a string only. Any suggestion? Thank you.

```
dataLine <- read.table('tabela301.csv', stringsAsFactors = F, sep=',', dec='.', header=T )
names(dataLine) <- c("Idade","total","0-4","5-9","10-14","15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34","35-39","40-44","45-49","50-54","55-59","60-64","65-69","70-74","75-79","80-84","85-89","90+")

grafico1 <- ggplot(dataLine, aes(x=dataLine$Idade, y=dataLine$`0-4`))  

for(i in colnames(dataLine)[3:21]){
 columns <- paste0("dataLine$",i)
  grafico1 + geom_line(aes(y=columns))
  }
```

Comment: Try using `aes_string` instead of `aes`. Also, the `paste0()` won't work. You can just use the column name directly in `aes_string`

Comment: Example code using built in R dataset: `for(i in c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")){
  print(ggplot(data=iris) + geom_line(aes_string(x = "Sepal.Length", y=i)))
}`